# KAFKA message restriction for a Publisher?

Tags: apache-kafka

We are using kafka 0.10.x, I am looking, if there is a way to stop a publisher kafka to stop sending messages after certain messages/limit is reached  in an hour. The goal here is to  restrict user to only send certain number messages in and hour/day ?
 If anyone has come across similar use case, please share your findings.
Thanks in Advance......

Comment: A possible alternative is to skip the extra messages on the consumer side (whatever is supposed to process them).

Answer (score 3):

Kafka has a few throttling and quota mechanisms but none of them exactly match your requirement to strictly limit a producer based on message count on a daily basis.

From the Apache Kafka 0.11.0.0 documentation at https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_quotas

> Kafka cluster has the ability to enforce quotas on requests to control
>   the broker resources used by clients. Two types of client quotas can
>   be enforced by Kafka brokers for each group of clients sharing a
>   quota:
>
> - Network bandwidth quotas define byte-rate thresholds (since 0.9)
> - Request rate quotas define CPU utilization thresholds as a percentage
>     of network and I/O threads (since 0.11)

Client quotas were first introduced in Kafka 0.9.0.0. Rate limits on producers and consumers are enforced to prevent clients saturating the network or monopolizing broker resources.

See KIP-13 for details: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-13+-+Quotas

The quota mechanism introduced on 0.9 was based on the client.id set in the client configuration, which can be changed easily. Ideally, quota should be set on the authenticated user name so it is not easy to circumvent so in 0.10.1.0 an addition Authenticated Quota feature was added.

See KIP-55 for details: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-55%3A+Secure+Quotas+for+Authenticated+Users

Both the quota mechanisms described above work on data volume (i.e. bandwidth throttling) and not on number of messages nor number of requests. If a client sends lots of small messages or makes lots of requests that return no messages (e.g., a consumer with min.byte configured to 0), it can still overwhelm the broker. To address this issue 0.11.0.0 added in additionally support for throttling by request rate.

See KIP-124 for details: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-124+-+Request+rate+quotas

With all that as background then, if you know that your producer always publishes messages of a certain size, then you can compute a daily limit expressed in MB and also a rate limit expressed in MB/sec which you can configure as a quota. That's not a perfect fit for your need because a producer might send nothing for 12 hours and then try and send at a faster rate for a short time and the quota would still limit them to a lower publish rate because the limit is enforced per second and not per day.

If you don't know the message size or it varies a lot then since messages are published using a produce request, you could use request rate throttling to somewhat control the rate that an authenticated user is allow to publish messages but again it would not be a message/day limit nor even a bandwidth limit but rather as a "CPU utilization threshold as a percentage of network and I/O threads". This helps more for avoiding DoS problems and not really for limiting message counts.

If you would like to see message count quotas or message storage quotas added to Kafka then clearly the Kafka Improvement Proposal (KIP) process works and you are encouraged to submit improvement proposals in this or any other area.

See KIP process for details: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Improvement+Proposals

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of broker configs:

**message.max.bytes** (default:1000000) – Maximum size of a message the broker will accept. This has to be smaller than the consumer fetch.message.max.bytes, or the broker will have messages that can’t be consumed, causing consumers to hang. 
**log.segment.bytes** (default: 1GB) – size of a Kafka data file. Make sure its larger than 1 message. Default should be fine (i.e. large messages probably shouldn’t exceed 1GB in any case. Its a messaging system, not a file system) 
**replica.fetch.max.bytes** (default: 1MB) – Maximum size of data that a broker can replicate. This has to be larger than message.max.bytes, or
a broker will accept messages and fail to replicate them. Leading to potential data loss.

I think you can tweak the config to do what you want